# Cerrar aplicación al desconectar USB que la contiene

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

estoy desarrollando una aplicación que se va a ejecutar desde un pendrive.

El problema viene al desconectar el Pendrive del equipo, lo que necesitaría es que se cerrara la aplicación, pero al ser el propio pendrive el que contiene el ejecutable (y por tanto el código), cuando lo desconecto la aplicación se mantiene abierta solo que cuando interactúo con ella, saltan errores.

No se si es posible lo que pido pero no se por donde agarrarlo y por tanto no se como empezar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo empezaria listando los puertos USB y guardando el identificador del puerto que recibe la usb donde corre la app, te dejo esto, tal vez te sirve http://janaxelson.com/hidpage.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente pude hacerlo con el siguiente código:

```
Private WM_DEVICECHANGE As Integer = &H219

Public Enum WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS As Integer
    DBT_CONFIGCHANGECANCELED = &H19
    DBT_CONFIGCHANGED = &H18
    DBT_CUSTOMEVENT = &H8006
    DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = &H8000
    DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE = &H8001
    DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVEFAILED = &H8002
    DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = &H8004
    DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING = &H8003
    DBT_DEVICETYPESPECIFIC = &H8005
    DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED = &H7
    DBT_QUERYCHANGECONFIG = &H17
    DBT_USERDEFINED = &HFFFF
End Enum

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
        If m.WParam = WM_DEVICECHANGE_WPPARAMS.DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE Then
            Me.Close()
        End If


    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

En mi caso no necesitaría hacer la enumeración, simplemente con tener el valor del DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE podría hacerlo, pero dejo todo el fragmento por si pudiera serle de ayuda a alguien más.